# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am working in column of data tables which is of server side.

```
          column << roster.training_sets&.first&.title + (roster.training_sets.size>1 ? '<br><a class="fa-sm" data-target="#trainingSet-'+roster.id.to_s+'" data-toggle="modal" href="#">See more</a><div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelTrainingSet" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="trainingSet-' + roster.id.to_s + '" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title">विषयगत क्षेत्र</h5><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"> ×</span></button></div><div class="modal-body"><ul class="bg-light p-3" style="line-height: 30px;">' + (roster.training_sets.map {|t_set| t_set.title }).map(&:inspect).join('<br>') + '</ul></div></div></div></div>' : '')
```

It works fine. When I filter the data there is also no problem works fine. But when I reset my filter got an error undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass.

Solves this by adding

```
          column << roster.training_sets&.first&.title += (roster.training_sets.size>1 ? '<br><a class="fa-sm" data-target="#trainingSet-'+roster.id.to_s+'" data-toggle="modal" href="#">See more</a><div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelTrainingSet" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="trainingSet-' + roster.id.to_s + '" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title">विषयगत क्षेत्र</h5><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"> ×</span></button></div><div class="modal-body"><ul class="bg-light p-3" style="line-height: 30px;">' + (roster.training_sets.map {|t_set| t_set.title }).map(&:inspect).join('<br>') + '</ul></div></div></div></div>' : '')
```

Is this the good idea??

Comment: This code is too complicated to read. Please try to paste it in human readable mode. Also, this kind of code going to hurt you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

`roster.training_sets&.first&.title` returning nil. Use `to_s` to solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).